# Event Listeners Not Working After Route Change in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, nuxt.js, gsap

Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently working on a Nuxt3 project and facing an issue with mouseenter and mouseleave event listeners within my layout. These events work as expected on initial page load, but stop functioning after navigating to a different route. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

**Problem Description:**

I have a custom cursor component in a Nuxt3 app, implemented with Vue 3 Composition API. The component is used inside Default.vue layout. This component uses mouseenter and mouseleave events to trigger certain animations with GSAP. The events are attached to various elements (like `<a>`, `<button>`, etc.) within my layout. On initial page load, everything works fine. However, after a route change, the events do not fire for elements within the layout.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { nextTick, onBeforeUnmount, onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

import { useRoute } from 'nuxt/app'

const cursorRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const cursorBig = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const cursorSmall = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const withHover: Ref<Array<Element>> = ref([])

function init() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1100)
    return

  if (cursorRef.value) {
    cursorBig.value = cursorRef.value.querySelector('#cursor-big')
    cursorSmall.value = cursorRef.value.querySelector('#cursor-small')
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    withHover.value = [
      ...Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a')),
      ...Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button')),
      ...Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('resource-card')),
      ...Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hover')),
    ]

    withHover.value.forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover)
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut)
    })

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseHover)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseHoverOut)
  }, 100)
  console.log('init cursor')
}

function destroy() {
  if (!withHover.value) {
    console.log('No Cursor exist')
    return
  }

  withHover.value.forEach((el) => {
    el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover)
    el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut)
  })

  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseHover)
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseHoverOut)
  console.log('destory cursor')
}

function onMouseMove(e: MouseEvent) {
  gsap.to(cursorBig.value, {
    x: e.clientX - 12,
    y: e.clientY - 12,
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 0.4,
  })
  gsap.to(cursorSmall.value, {
    x: e.clientX - 2,
    y: e.clientY - 2,
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 0.1,
  })
}

function onMouseHover() {
  console.log('Mouse hover')
  gsap.to(cursorBig.value, { scale: 3, duration: 0.3 })
}

function onMouseHoverOut() {
  console.log('Mouse hover out')
  gsap.to(cursorBig.value, { scale: 1, duration: 0.3 })
}

onMounted(() => {
  destroy()
  init()
})

onBeforeUnmount(destroy)

const route = useRoute()

watch(() => route.path, async () => {
  destroy()
  await nextTick()
  init()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="cursorRef" class="custom-cursor">
    <div id="cursor-big" class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--big" />
    <div id="cursor-small" class="custom-cursor__ball custom-cursor__ball--small" />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .custom-cursor__ball {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }

  .custom-cursor__ball--big {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    @apply bg-white-100;
  }

  .custom-cursor__ball--small {
    content: '';
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
</style>
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

I've tried reinitializing the event listeners on route change using a watcher on route.path.
Used nextTick to ensure DOM elements are available when reinitializing.
Ensured proper cleanup in onBeforeUnmount.

**Questions:**

Is there a more effective way to reattach event listeners to DOM elements that persist across routes?
Could this issue be related to the Vue lifecycle or the way Nuxt handles page transitions?
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!